# SSLHandshakeException during sending report by Crashlytics in Android

Tags: android, crashlytics

I get:

```
D/CrashlyticsCore: Attempting to send 4 report(s)
E/CrashlyticsCore: Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport@e6586d3
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2546)
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2526)
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2512)
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.applyMultipartDataTo(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:89)
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:61)
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:18)
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader.forceUpload(ReportUploader.java:104)
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:242)
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:185)
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
 at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.openOutput(HttpRequest.java:2450)
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.startPart(HttpRequest.java:2463)
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2542)
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2526) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2512) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.applyMultipartDataTo(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:89) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:61) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:18) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader.forceUpload(ReportUploader.java:104) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:242) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:185) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:329)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103) 
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) 
 at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.openOutput(HttpRequest.java:2450) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.startPart(HttpRequest.java:2463) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2542) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2526) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2512) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.applyMultipartDataTo(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:89) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:61) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:18) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader.forceUpload(ReportUploader.java:104) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:242) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:185) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:329) 
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:230) 
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115) 
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556) 
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103) 
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) 
 at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) 
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.openOutput(HttpRequest.java:2450) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.startPart(HttpRequest.java:2463) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2542) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2526) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2512) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.applyMultipartDataTo(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:89) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:61) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:18) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader.forceUpload(ReportUploader.java:104) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:242) 
 at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:185) 
 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any help??

Comment: did u fix it???